# Length of linear combination of vectors given the vector lengths and dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v$ and $w$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\|v\| = 4$, $\| w\| = 3$, and $v \cdot w = 8$. If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, express the length of $av + bw$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

I'm not sure how to solve this question or what it is asking.

Comment: Well, how do you find the length of a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking: if you have two vectors $v$ and $w$, you scale them each by a different amount ($a$ and $b$ respectively) and then add them together head-to-tail, what is the length of that sum? It may help to draw a picture.

It should be clear from the picture that to answer the question you need to know (i) the length of the two vectors, and (ii) the angle between them. Fortunately that's exactly the information the problem has provided. In terms of algebra, we have

$$\|av+bw\| = \sqrt{(av+bw)\cdot(av+bw)} = \sqrt{a^2v\cdot v  + 2abv\cdot w + b^2w\cdot w}.$$

Do you understand how I got this expression? Can you finish simplying it to get the final answer?

Comment: Yes, I understand how you got that. Now, in order to determine v dot v, would I just multiply the length of v by itself?

Comment: @BobParker Yep!

Comment: How do I justify that? Because I am multiplying the lengths together, not the actual vectors of v.

Comment: @BobParker It's simply the formula $\|v\|^2 = v\cdot v$ (Pythagorean theorem)

Comment: Oh okay. I ended up with (16a^2 + 16ab + 16b^2)^(1/2). Is this the most I can simplify?

Comment: @BobParker I think you made a mistake in your calculation.

Comment: I just multiplied v dot v (16) to the first term, v dot w (8) to the second term, and v dot v again to the third term.

Comment: @BobParker Ah, the mistake is in my formula :) Clearly the last term should be $w\cdot w$, not $v\cdot v$.

Comment: Gotcha. So I got (16a^2 + 16ab + 9b^2)^(1/2)

Comment: @BobParker And that's the best you can do without knowing $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks so much :)